# Altering numbering of lightbox images

Tags: lightbox2

I am using lightbox to act as a gallery, where the gallery is split over several pages. For example, page 1 contains images 1 to 50, page 2 contains images 51 to 100.

I would like to manipulate the image number shown below the image (shown below the caption when lightbox is open) so that when the first image on page 2 is clicked, it reads "Image 51 of 100", even though there are in fact only 50 images on that page.

I've identified the "imageCountLabel" function within lighbox's JS, but haven't been able to dynamically alter "currentImageNum" or "totalImages" to achieve the desired outcome. Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

just change the data-lightbox="example-set" to data-lightbox="example-set1" on page2.